# Free Software to be able to extend my current desktop a monitor on another computer screen?

Tags: windows, display, multi-monitor

I'm asking because Projecting it in Windows doesn't seem to work for me. Does anyone know of some good, free, software?

Or failing that, something cheap (like $10, no subscription)?

Both laptops (my main one ) and the one with the display I want to use are Windows 11

Comment: From your description and comment, Projecting is what you are asking for.  Why does it not work ?

Comment: @RohitGupta it just didn't work, I can't describe it better - but yeah that was my go to choice if it worked... however I didn't test it in 22H2... 22H2 is the most awesome version of windows ever.. it fix the majorly huge virtual desktop bug that made it a risky proposition to drag a window to another desktop (high chance of explorer crashing if that happened in windows 10 and 11 but they finally fixed it with 22H2. sure it doesn't affect everyone but it affected me on all my machines, so probably because of some useful running software utility - no idea which, so maybe they fixed this too?)

Answer (score 0):

Would [Mouse-Without-Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460) do what you want?  It basically shares the desktop between two computers, so you can use both at the same time from one user input.

Comment: don't think so.. i sounds from the little description there that it is more like syngery (or the superior unless you want cross platform - Input Director).. essentially a software KVM without the V. I want to be able to for example drag a window from my main laptop to the secondary laptop screen.

Comment: I don't think I have any other suggestions besides a VNC or Remote Desktop type application.  I think with some you can keep using the desktop on both PC's... >_>

Not sure why the windows built-in application might not be working.  That might be worth looking into.

Comment: probably because Microsoft switched, Windows starting with Windows 10, into a release model where the QA is not as good as it used to be